# This Snippet is not working on Safari 5.1.7 (Windows)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#btn').bind('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $d('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');
});
```

I want to bind or say want to trigger the browser window by a click of another button. Above code works fine in all other browsers. Only Safari 5.1.7(Windows) is unable to compile it.

> And for note My Console is free of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Again it's my turn..haha..
So after searching & searching I figured out that there is no issue with the above code, it's clean & simple. But the problem is with the browser Safari 5.1.7(Windows) as it's not considering the `<input type="file" name="">` with `CSS:: display:none` added to it.

So instead of `display:none` I used `height & width = 0` & `visibility = hidden`

That's all, now it works as great as I want it to.

> Cheers!